# How to compare two lists to find common and not common items

Tags: c#, data-structures, mvvm, .net-6.0

I need to compare two lists to find common items and not common items.

I think this code should explain everything:

```
public class Tool {
    public string Name {get;set;};
}

List<Tool> ToolsRequired = 
    new List<Tool>()
    {
        new Tool(){Name = "Screwdriver"},
        new Tool(){Name = "Chainsaw"},
        new Tool(){Name = "Wrench"},
        new Tool(){Name = "Hammer"}
    };

List<Tool> ToolsInBag = 
    new List<Tool>()
    {
        new Tool(){Name = "Screwdriver"},
        new Tool(){Name = "Chainsaw"},
        new Tool(){Name = "Wrench"},
        new Tool(){Name = "Axe"}
    };

public class CompareToolsetsResult {
    List<Tool> CompletedTools;
    List<Tool> MissingTools;
    List<Tool> UnnecessaryTools;
}

public CompareToolsetsResult CompareToolsets(
    List<Tool> toolsInBag, 
    List<Tool> toolsRequired
){
    // do I have to iterate lists two times to build CompareToolsetsResult?
}

var result = CompareToolsets(ToolsInBag, ToolsRequired);
```

Expected result view (mockup made in Excel):

[image]

Questions:

- do I have to iterate lists two times to build CompareToolsetsResult, or maybe .NET has something built-in for "synchronization" like this?
- is my "CompareToolsetsResult" class good idea, or maybe there is better way / data structure to hold function result for this scenario? All these items will be finally displayed on single WPF ListView, with GroupItem/Expander feature with proper formatting and I want to avoid messing around with too much data processing before I put the result

I was thinking about something like this:

```
public enum ItemCompareStatus { OK, Missing, Unnecessary};

public class CompareResult<T> {
    public T Item {get; set;};
    public ItemCompareStatus Status {get; set;};
}
```

and returning list of `CompareResult<T>` instead of `CompareToolsetsResult`.

**But is it worth to do this?**

It looks more efficient. I can build this during comparison, and then pass List<CompareResult> directly to my ViewModel and bind ListView with grouping directly to this list without messing around).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**LINQ**

You can use LINQ's [`Intersect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=net-6.0) and [`Except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-6.0) methods to get what you need.

The `Intercect` method will return elements that are shared between the two lists.

```cs
var commonItems = list1.Intersect(list2);
```

And the `Except` method will do the oposite, return the elements contained in the first list, but not in the second.

```cs
var list1OnlyItems = list1.Except(list2);
var list2OnlyItems = list2.Except(list1);
```

**Performance**

I decided to run a little benchmark (using BenchmarkDotNet) to get an idea of how performant the manual vs LINQ version of the code was. In short - manual was faster.

*NOTE that this doesn't matter too much. The difference I got during the benchmarks was in microseconds, that's not anything to worry about in a client app.*

The following benchmark runs three implementations of the same thing:

- Manual: manually looping through all the items and checking their status
- Linq: using the `Intercect` and `Except` methods to get the items with different statuses
- Mixed: a combination of Manual and Linq

Here are the bechmark results:

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen0 | Gen1 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Manual | 1.300 us | 0.0126 us | 0.0117 us | 0.2155 | - | 1.33 KB |
| Linq | 2.417 us | 0.0435 us | 0.0407 us | 0.7019 | 0.0038 | 4.3 KB |
| Mixed | 1.592 us | 0.0207 us | 0.0194 us | 0.4463 | 0.0019 | 2.73 KB |

**Summary**

Is manual faster? Yes! But does it matter? That's up to everyone to decide.

I'd personally be happy to use LINQ where I can, because it usually makes the code more readable and shorter than writing the thing manually. I can take the little performance hit, at least on the client apps, a server app might be a different story.

**Benchmark Code**

Here's the code used to run the benchmark:

```cs
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;

namespace CommonItemsBenchmarks;

[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class Benchy
{
    private readonly List<string> _required = new()
    {
        "Screwdriver",
        "Chainsaw",
        "Wrench",
        "Hammer",
        "Mallet",
        "Scissors",
        "Chisel",
        "Pliers",
        "Drill",
        "Tape measure",
        "Soldering iron",
        "Electric screwdriver",
        "Nail gun",
        "Monkeywrench",
        "Phillips screwdriver",
        "Scraper"
    };

    private readonly List<string> _current = new()
    {
        "Screwdriver",
        "Chainsaw",
        "Wrench",
        "Axe",
        "Coping saw",
        "Wire",
        "Washer",
        "Shovel"
    };

    private readonly ManualItemComparer _manualItemComparer = new();
    private readonly LinqItemComparer _linqItemComparer = new();
    private readonly MixedItemComparer _mixedItemComparer = new();

    [Benchmark]
    public void Manual()
    {
        _ = _manualItemComparer.CompareSets(_required, _current);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Linq()
    {
        _ = _linqItemComparer.CompareSets(_required, _current);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Mixed()
    {
        _ = _mixedItemComparer.CompareSets(_required, _current);
    }
}

public class MixedItemComparer : IItemComparer
{
    public IEnumerable<CompareResult<T>> CompareSets<T>(IEnumerable<T> requiredItems, IEnumerable<T> currentItems)
    {
        var result = currentItems
            .Except(requiredItems)
            .Select(a => new CompareResult<T>(a, ItemCompareStatus.Unnecessary))
            .ToList();

        foreach (var required in requiredItems)
        {
            if (currentItems.Contains(required))
            {
                result.Add(new CompareResult<T>(required, ItemCompareStatus.OK));
            }
            else
            {
                result.Add(new CompareResult<T>(required, ItemCompareStatus.Missing));
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}

public class ManualItemComparer : IItemComparer
{
    public IEnumerable<CompareResult<T>> CompareSets<T>(IEnumerable<T> requiredItems, IEnumerable<T> currentItems)
    {
        var result = new List<CompareResult<T>>();

        foreach (var required in requiredItems)
        {
            if (currentItems.Contains(required))
            {
                result.Add(new CompareResult<T>(required, ItemCompareStatus.OK));
            }
            else
            {
                result.Add(new CompareResult<T>(required, ItemCompareStatus.Missing));
            }
        }

        foreach (var current in currentItems)
        {
            if (!requiredItems.Contains(current))
            {
                result.Add(new CompareResult<T>(current, ItemCompareStatus.Unnecessary));
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}

public class LinqItemComparer : IItemComparer
{
    public IEnumerable<CompareResult<T>> CompareSets<T>(IEnumerable<T> requiredItems, IEnumerable<T> currentItems)
    {
        var result = new List<CompareResult<T>>();

        var present = requiredItems
            .Intersect(currentItems)
            .Select(a => new CompareResult<T>(a, ItemCompareStatus.OK));

        result.AddRange(present);

        var missing = requiredItems
            .Except(currentItems)
            .Select(a => new CompareResult<T>(a, ItemCompareStatus.Missing));

        result.AddRange(missing);

        var unnecesary = currentItems
            .Except(requiredItems)
            .Select(a => new CompareResult<T>(a, ItemCompareStatus.Unnecessary));

        result.AddRange(unnecesary);

        return result;
    }
}

public interface IItemComparer
{
    IEnumerable<CompareResult<T>> CompareSets<T>(IEnumerable<T> requiredItems, IEnumerable<T> currentItems);
}

public enum ItemCompareStatus { OK, Missing, Unnecessary };

public class CompareResult<T>
{
    public T Item { get; set; }
    public ItemCompareStatus Status { get; set; }

    public CompareResult(T item, ItemCompareStatus status)
    {
        Item = item;
        Status = status;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts and benchmark code. I have to check the difference on ARM. Maybe it will matter on battery operated device, like tablet or phone. And manual comparison is not that bad and ugly.